# C - scanf variable while it is not an integer

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, integer, scanf

I want my function to read my variable while it is not an integer. My teacher taught us to do it using the form `var=scanf("%d", &x)` and if it is a string, it will be equal to zero. However, when I enter a string, the while loop repeats without asking me to re-enter a value.

Here's my algorithm:

```
int returnValue(int a, int b)
{
    int x, r;
    do{
        printf("Enter a value between %d and %d.\n", a, b);
        r=scanf("%d", &x);
    }while(x<a || x > b || r==0);
    return x;
}
```

If someone has any idea of the problem, it would be great.

Comment: Is your actual question, "How do I read in a line of input and parse it to see if it contains an integer?"

Answer (score 2):

> while loop repeats without asking me to re-enter a value.

The non-numeric input that did not covert to an `int` remains in `stdin` for the next I/O operation.  Same offending input is read again each loop in OP's code. 
 Code should read and discard the non-numeric input.

I recommend to not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.
In the meantime, use `fgets()` to read *line* of user input.

```
int returnValue(int a, int b) {
  char buf[40];  // Suggest a size twice the expected max.
  int x, r;
  do {
    printf("Enter a value between %d and %d [inclusive].\n", a, b);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf. stdin) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "End-of-file or input error\n");
      return INT_MIN;  // Or some other invalid value.    
    }
    int r = sscanf(buf, "%d", &x);  // or look into strtol() as a more robust solution
  } while(r != 1 || x < a || x > b); // test r first else x is undefined.
  return x;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In example code here, `INT_MIN`.  A more robust approach could use `int returnValue(int *dest, int a, int b)` saving  the  result in `*dest` and returning 1 for success or `EOF` on end-of-file.

Comment: Yes, I saw the edit just after posting the comment (and thought you must read minds too...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My compatriot SO-er, we all bring to the table different gifts.